# Accessing a child node by name of an XML document using C#

Tags: c#, xml

I have a situation which an XML document contained something similar to the following, but then the order of the "Block" elements was changed, and in an application, I was accessing the value of the  in  by using GetElementsByTagName("Amount")[0].InnerText, as it was the first occurrence of "Amount". Then the order of the "Blocks" changed, and the "Amount" returned by the GetElementsByTagName was still the first occurrence, but I want the "Amount" in "Block1" to always be returned. How do I accomplish this in C#?

**Before:**

```
<Response xmlns="testsite.com/schema/TestService/2015-01-01">
  <Block1>
     <Amount>$5.00</Amount>
  </Block1>
  <Block2>
     <Amount>$0.00</Amount>
  </Block2>
  <Block3>
     <Amount>$0.00</Amount>
  </Block3>
</Response>
```

**After:**

```
<Response xmlns="testsite.com/schema/TestService/2015-01-01">
  <Block2>
     <Amount>$0.00</Amount>
  </Block2>
  <Block3>
     <Amount>$0.00</Amount>
  </Block3>
  <Block1>
     <Amount>$5.00</Amount>
  </Block1>
</Response>
```

C#:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(response);

string amount = doc.GetElementsByTagName("Amount")[0].InnerText;
```

Comment: kyle, I added an answer with your new requirment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use method `SelectSingleNode` and XPath expression to access the data that you need. You also need to use namespace manager and import correct namespace:

```
var namespaceManager= new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
namespaceManager.AddNamespace("a", "testsite.com/schema/TestService/2015-01-01");

var xmlNode = doc.SelectSingleNode("/a:Response/a:Block1/a:Amount", namespaceManager);
var value = node.InnerText;    // prints $5.00
```

Such code would find you correct value regardless of where Block1 is - first, second or third element. The method `SelectSingleNode` returns first node that matches an expression, so if you have more than one Block1 element in your XML then the results might be not what you expect

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for...however, in my root element I have something like <Response xmlns="http://testsite.com/schema/TestService/2015-01-01"> and with the quoted value, it's giving me a NULL reference exception, even after I escape the quotes...please see my updated original post.

Comment: Looks like you updated our answer...this worked 100%, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

> however, in my root element I have something like `<Response xmlns="testsite.com/schema/TestService/2015-01-01">`

It is the default xmlnamespece of your xml. With the new info you provided

```
XmlNamespaceManager mgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
mgr.AddNamespace("ns", "testsite.com/schema/TestService/2015-01-01");

var value = doc.SelectSingleNode("/ns:Response/ns:Block1/ns:Amount", mgr).InnerText;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this was what I was looking for. Do you have any suggestions for reading up on this?

Answer (score 0):

Start with System.Xml.Linq; You'll want to load your xml file and then parse your document. For example,

```
var doc = XDocument.Load("file.xml");
IEnumerable<XElement> elements = doc.Descendants(tagNameHere);
```

And if you want to create a list of those descendants, you can access those elements by doing something like this:

```
List<string> myElements = new List<string>();
XElement element = elements.ElementAt(0);
myElements.Add(element.Value);
```

This is just to get you started. I suggest you read here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq(v=vs.110).aspx